# How to Access URL of Localhost Django Project - Page Not Found

Tags: python, django, localhost, celery

I transferred my Django project from a Ubuntu server that is currently serving the website. I'm trying to run this project on a localhost MacOSX environment for testing purposes. The command I'm familiar with for Django projects is:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

After which when I input 127.0.0.1:8000 into a browser, the project displays.

But my Ubuntu server is not currently running a script in that form, rather in the form of

```
python manage.py celeryd
```

My knowledge of how celery interfaces with Django is somewhat limited so this question may be very basic, but I can't find the URL to display the project.

On my Mac server, when I run:

```
python manage.py celeryd
```

the script does not error out on me--instead, it appears to be working by displaying this:

[image]

However, I don't know how to access the project. When I put 127.0.0.1 in the browser (and many other possible variations using different ports), I get Page Not Found.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`?

Comment: I did, and while the page was found, it gave me a Template Syntax Error:

`'core' is not a valid tag library: Template library core not found, tried django.templatetags.core`

1 `{% load core %}`

2 `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

Comment: @ternto333 - I have answered for a different question, same as your comment above belongs to. How the question is different now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to define 'core' template tag in one of your apps templatetags library say `custom_tags.py`. Make sure that this app is added to INSTALLED_APPS in settings. Then in your html template add

```
{% load custom_tags %}
```

It will fix the error you are getting. For more details please read [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Comment: I have answered a different question. How my answer could now be attached to this question ?

Answer (score 2):

You seem confused about what celery is. It is not a webserver, and it won't serve pages for you. It is an offline task manager, useful for performing complex or long running jobs that aren't appropriate to do in the context of a web request.

You'll need an actual web server alongside celery to serve your site itself.